# Including Pusher php server in OctoberCMS with vinkla/pusher bridge

Tags: php, laravel-5, pusher, octobercms

I've started building a website in October CMS and now I'm trying to build a simple chat plugin that runs on Pusher. I've been following [this tutorial](https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/getting-started/laravel-pusher-bridge.html) written for Laravel, combined with October documentation.

Steps I've taken:

- Installed october through composer

Then as described in the tutorial:

- Installed [vinkla/pusher](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-pusher) package through composer
- Published the package and set the config

Then in the cms I made a new Chat plugin with component and registered the service provider in the boot() function of Plugin.php file:

plugins/oda/chat/Plugin.php

```
<?php namespace Oda\Chat;

use Backend;
use App;
use System\Classes\PluginBase;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

...

 public function boot()
 {
   App::register('Vinkla\Pusher\PusherServiceProvider');
 }

...

}
```

And in my plugin component I added the simple test code as described on the vinkla/pusher github:

plugins/oda/chat/components/Chat.php

```
<?php namespace Oda\Chat\Components;

use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use Vinkla\Pusher\Facades\Pusher;

class Chat extends ComponentBase
{

...

 public function onRun()
 {
    $data['message'] = 'hello world';
    Pusher::trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', $data);
 }

...

}
```

I added the component to a page and checked the pusher dashboard debugging, but nothing is received. Also no errors on the page itself.

Comment: Have you published your plugin? I'm working on a similar project and want to check if it's available. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that in the default options of the Pusher example 'encrypted' was set to true, removing this option from the config file solved the problem.

my config/pusher.php looks like this

```
'connections' => [

    'main' => [
        'auth_key' => 'put auth key here',
        'secret' => 'put secret key here',
        'app_id' => 'put app id here',
        'options' => ['cluster' => 'eu'],
        'host' => null,
        'port' => null,
        'timeout' => null,
    ],
```